# Why did Microsoft Azure Edge install a new kernel on my machine?

Tags: networking, kernel, virtualization, microsoft, azure

After installing Azure Edge (sudo apt-get install linux-azure-edge), a completely new Azure kernel was put on my machine that now boots in place of the old kernel (which no longer works). The new Azure kernel is practically non-functional and can do nothing except load docker.

Why did Azure install a completely new kernel and how can I revert it or get rid of it? It has removed most of the basic system packages.

Manual installations of newer kernels have been failing at the make step with the warnings LIBELF_NEED_LINK_H and LIBELF_NEED_SYS_LINK_H. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score -1):

`linux-azure-edge` is a kernel package developed by Canonical for Ubuntu VMs running on Microsoft Azure. Thus, installing this package will install a new kernel on your machine.

Comment: How did you connect this question to the Edge browser? This isn't mentioned anywhere - OP is clearly asking about the kernel .. 

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I made too many assumptions here, I will clarify my answer.